# how to close login form while being redirected to the main form java

Tags: java

I'm making a login form in java and i having trouble with the it. Whats happening is that regardless of whether the username are correct or not the form closes. I know that the dispose; isn't suppose to be placed in its position but everytime that i attempt to place it elsewhere I'm having error in my code. This is the code that I have

```
        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            String user=jTextField1.getText();
            String pwd= new String (jPasswordField1.getPassword());
        if (user.equals("admin") && pwd.equals("1234"))
            new Main().setVisible(true);
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorrect Username or Password!");
        }
        dispose;
}
```

I'm fairly new to java, so please help me

Comment: Main.java code please

Comment: dispose is a method you need brackets to call it >> dispose();

Comment: Show us where you try to call dispose